# event.stopPropagation() fails on ReactJS Component inside a native HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My particular use case of React is thus:

I wish to add a small React Component to a card that is an existing, fully-functional HTML element, per all the cards on the page. This React Component shall serve to implement a new feature on those cards : reverting changes.

**The HTML (well, the MVCE version of it)**

is something like this:

```
<div id="some-id" class="card float-sm-left menu-visual-card " onclick="(function(event) { console.log('I got clicked, and a modal will spawn' ) })(event)">
    <div class=card-block>
        <h5 class="card-title format-text">Some title</h5>
        <!-- some business elements here -->
    </div>
    <!-- card footer -->
    <div class=customized-indicator-react></div>
</div>
```

**The React Component**

in its tl;dr version is the following:

```
class CustomizedIndicatorComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props)

        // business logic
        let active = this.props.active

        this.state = {
            active : active
        }
    }

    toggleActive = () => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            active : !this.state.active
        })
    }

    // setup
    componentDidMount() { 
        // here's where I tried to add a jQuery onclick listener to stop propagation, only to have the React Component listener get stopped
    }

    // teardown
    componentWillUnmount() { 
        console.log("CustomizedIndicatorComponent destroyed!")
    }

    // the UI logic
    render() {
        if (this.state.active) { 
            return (
                <div>
                    <div 
                        className="badge badge-sm badge-info float-sm-left customized"
                        style={{marginRight:"10px"}}
                    >Customized</div>
                    <div 
                        onClick={(e) => { 
                            e.stopPropagation()
                            this.toggleActive()
                        }}
                        title="Click to undo customizations">
                        <i className="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        return <div />
    }
}
```

**What happens when you run this?**

When I run this, it renders. However, when I click the widget to "de-activate" the element, the container's event-handler still fires!!

I know there is a slew of internet questions about this issue or something close to it, but none of the ones I could find seem to be about this exact use case.

Also, adding an event listener in `componentDidMount` doesn't work, as that [prevents **anything** from firing](https://fortes.com/2018/react-and-dom-events/)!

Is there any way I can make this work without wasting developer-hours refactoring everything including the parent HTMLElements?

Answer (score 0):

A "hacky" way you may consider is to get the parent's id from inside the React component and disable the click event from there.

If `id` could not be passed as a property to the React component, you can try using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.getAttribute("id")` to get it and then disable the event using:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

Comment: Would this logic take place in constructor, componentDidMount, or render ?

Comment: @MikeWarren It depends on how and when you'd like to disable the container's click event. If you'd like to have it as the React component renders, then you should considering havng it inside `componentDidMount`; if you want the user to have the control over enabling/disabling the click event, then you can add it to the click handler of the button in the React component.